# Get item from SQLite database with use OnItemClickListener in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, syntax, onitemclicklistener

I want to get item from my database when i use OnItemClickListener in my ListView, but i don't know the syntax how to do that.

The other say i must implement onListItemClick method, i try to use that but i got force close, maybe my syntax is just wrong.

Can you give suggestion with code how to do that. I got frustrated because of this. I really thank you for those who answer this question.

Here's my code, please give intention to onItemClick mehod:

```
public class HotelList extends ListActivity{
hotelHelper dbHotelHelper;
protected Cursor cursor;
protected ListAdapter adapter;
ListView numberList;    

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.hotellist);

    numberList = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    numberList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String query = "SELECT lat, long FROM hoteltbl WHERE name = '" + selectedItem[THIS IS THE PROBLEM: the syntax to get selected item] + "'";
            SQLiteDatabase dbs = dbHotelHelper.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor result = dbs.rawQuery(query, null);
            result.moveToFirst();

            double lat = result.getDouble(result.getColumnIndex("lat"));
            double longi = result.getDouble(result.getColumnIndex("long"));

            Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&saddr=&daddr="+lat+","+longi));
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    });



    dbHotelHelper = new hotelHelper(this);
    try{
        dbHotelHelper.createDataBase();         
    }
    catch (Exception ioe){
        Log.e("err","Unable to create database");
    }        
    view();   


    }


private void view() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHotelHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    try{
        cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM hoteltbl", null);
        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                this, 
                R.layout.hotelview, 
                cursor, 
                new String[]{"name"}, 
                new int[] {R.id.hotelname}
                );
        numberList.setAdapter(adapter);     
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("error",e.toString());
    }       
}
```

}

Here's the LogCat:

```
11-28 20:44:10.449: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(856): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-28 20:44:10.449: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(856): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-28 20:44:10.449: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(856):     at com.william.placefinder.HotelList$1.onItemClick(HotelList.java:40)
11-28 20:44:10.449: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(856):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
11-28 20:44:10.449: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(856):     at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3382)
11-28 20:44:10.449: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(856):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1696)
11-28 20:44:10.449: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(856):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
11-28 20:44:10.449: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(856):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-28 20:44:10.449: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(856):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-28 20:44:10.449: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(856):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
11-28 20:44:10.449: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(856):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-28 20:44:10.449: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(856):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-28 20:44:10.449: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(856):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
11-28 20:44:10.449: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(856):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
11-28 20:44:10.449: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(856):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: can you please post your logcat trace?

Comment: i think it must edit in this syntax: String query = "SELECT lat, long FROM hoteltbl WHERE name = '" + **selectedItem[THIS IS THE PROBLEM: the syntax to get selected item]** + "'";

Comment: that syntax above located in onItemClick method, any idea how to make the "selectedItem" variable get data from database?

Comment: I think you should use `String query = "SELECT lat, long FROM hoteltbl WHERE name = '" + selectedItem[arg2] + "'";` will get the selected item at that position.

Comment: Thx for the answer. I just implement the syntax you give above, the problem is how can i declare the variable selectedItem[args2]? Must i use string or char?

Comment: It doesn't matter as you concatenate it into a `String` - it will get converted into a `String`.

Comment: I declare it as "private String[] selectedItem;" but i got force close when i click the item on listview. Any idea how to declare it? Sorry i'm asking too much for this, cause i really newbie in android.

Comment: i think you should get your hotel name form your listview first(hope you are getting the listview correctly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you are loading only the Hotel Names to your ListView. 
I think you should get your hotel name form your listview first(hope you are getting the listview correctly).                              In your `onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3)`, add this first.

```
String selectedItem = (String) numberList.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
```

Then pass it to your select query.

Comment: Buddy thx for your answer, it's inspire me. I not use that code you gave, but i use this `long selectedItem = numberList.getItemIdAtPosition(arg2);` and it work.